# How do I pull a report summary to a Visualforce page as simple plain text results?

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, metadata, rest, reports-api

How do I pull a report summary to a Visualforce page as simple plain text results?

I've been searching all over and haven't found a simple solution. All examples are confusing and all code has to be customized beyond my abilities.

Anyone have a simple copy and paste solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code that is used to display report results on a vf page :

**Controller :**

```
public with sharing class AsyncReportController {

public List<SelectOption> availableReports { get; set; }
public Id reportId { get; set; }
public Id instanceId { get; set; }
public Boolean reportIsRunning { get; set; }
private transient Reports.ReportResults reportResults;

public AsyncReportController() {
    availableReports = retrieveAvailableReports();
}

public List<SelectOption> retrieveAvailableReports() {
    List<SelectOption> reptOpts = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (Report r : [
         Select Id, Name
         From Report
         Where Format = 'Tabular'
         Order By Name
    ]) {
        reptOpts.add(new SelectOption(r.Id, r.Name));
    }
    return reptOpts;
}

public PageReference runReport() {
    Reports.ReportInstance reportInstance = Reports.ReportManager.runAsyncReport(reportId, true);
    instanceId = reportInstance.getId();
    processInstance(reportInstance);

    return null;
}

public PageReference checkForReportResults() {
    Reports.ReportInstance reportInstance = Reports.ReportManager.getReportInstance(instanceId);
    processInstance(reportInstance);

    return null;
}

private void processInstance(Reports.ReportInstance reportInstance) {
    reportIsRunning = reportInstance.getStatus() == 'Running' || reportInstance.getStatus() == 'New';
    if (!reportIsRunning) {
        reportResults = reportInstance.getReportResults();
    }
}

public Reports.ReportResults getReportResults() {
    return reportResults;
}
```

}

**VFPage :**

To run the report from page:

```
 <apex:form >
      <apex:actionPoller action="{!checkForReportResults}" id="poller" reRender="reportResults" interval="5" enabled="{!reportIsRunning}" />
      <apex:commandButton action="{!runReport}" reRender="poller,reportResults" value="Run Report"/>
 </apex:form>
```

Set column values in table:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!reportResults.reportMetadata.detailColumns}" var="colName">
              <th><apex:outputText value="{!reportResults.reportExtendedMetadata.detailColumnInfo[colName].label}"/></th>
           </apex:repeat>
```

Set row values :

```
       <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!reportResults.factMap['T!T'].rows}" var="row">
               <tr>
                   <apex:repeat value="{!row.dataCells}" var="cell">
                       <td><apex:outputText value="{!cell.label}"/></td>
                   </apex:repeat>
               </tr>
           </apex:repeat>
       </tbody>
```

Comment: Ok do i paste all that in the body of the VF page?
Do i create a new controller for the first part?
Do i do that through the developer console?
Is it a Apex Class or Trigger or VF Page?
What do i name the controller?

Comment: Ok so i created a new controller through sandbox and pushed it through the production(simply copy and pasting your code) do i need to edit/customize it in any way? Then when i paste the rest of the code into the apex page i get this error: Error: <apex:actionPoller> (under <apex:page>) must occur between <apex:form></apex:form> tags. 
what do i do? if i add the <apex:form> i get other errors regarding: "reportIsRunning" help.

Comment: Ok now I see the controller wasn't deployed because it only had a 61% code coverage and needed to be at 75%.

Comment: Did this solve your question?

Comment: how i can put filters in this code for tabular report.
I need filters urgerntly. Regards
Mahendra

Comment: The problem with Test User's solution is it won't report on more that 1000 rows by virtue of governor limits on the apex:repeat tag.... I haven't figured out a way round this - does anyone have any ideas?

If there was a way to make the report "readonly=true" it would return up to 10,000 rows but apparently that tag isn't available :-(

It seems like by common sense reports should be "readonly" -- but this is not the case.